Not Authorized to access method on type Query AWS Amplify AppSync
I am facing an authorization issue with AWS AppSync when querying data that should be accessible by the logged-in user. Despite being logged in with a valid user who owns the data, AppSync returns an "Unauthorized" error when I attempt to query the user's data.
Error Message:
{
  "data": {
    "getXXXXXXUserAccount": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "getXXXXXXUserAccount"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "Unauthorized",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "Not Authorized to access getXXXXXXUserAccount on type Query"
    }
  ]
}

GraphQL Query:
query MyQuery {
  getXXXXXXUserAccount(id: "c13cdc53-8a2b-4d05-8ede-5fc66a8ac4e3") {
    id
  }
}

AWS Amplify AppSync Schema:
type XXXXXXUserAccount @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, operations: [create, read, update, delete] }]) {
...
}

I've checked the IAM auth policy for the project, and it looks like everything is there:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "appsync:GraphQL",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:appsync:XXXXXXXXXXX:apis/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/types/XXXXXXXXXXXXXContactForm/*",
                "arn:aws:appsync:XXXXXXXXXXX:apis/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/types/Query/fields/getXXXXXXXXXXXXXContactForm",
                "arn:aws:appsync:XXXXXXXXXXX:apis/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/types/Query/fields/listXXXXXXXXXXXXXContactForms",
                "arn:aws:appsync:XXXXXXXXXXX:apis/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/types/Mutation/fields/createXXXXXXXXXXXXXContactForm",
                "arn:aws:appsync:XXXXXXXXXXX:apis/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/types/Mutation/fields/updateXXXXXXXXXXXXXContactForm",
                "arn:aws:appsync:XXXXXXXXXXX:apis/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/types/Mutation/fields/deleteXXXXXXXXXXXXXContactForm",
                "arn:aws:appsync:XXXXXXXXXXX:apis/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/types/Subscription/fields/onCreateXXXXXXXXXXXXXContactForm",
                "arn:aws:appsync:XXXXXXXXXXX:apis/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/types/Subscription/fields/onUpdateXXXXXXXXXXXXXContactForm",
                "arn:aws:appsync:XXXXXXXXXXX:apis/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/types/Subscription/fields/onDeleteXXXXXXXXXXXXXContactForm"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}```




You can check:

IAM authRole policy for your project
Ensure the owner field is present in your DynamoDB entry and is the same as the cognito userSub.
Login to your user via AppSync and test it before using the front-end.

In my case, it was point 2.
